# JOOQ:How to use alias in complex Select statement?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Here is my select statement

```
SelectQuery<Record> selectQueryPayment = transaction.selectQuery();
    selectQueryPayment.addSelect(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_NUMBER,AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_AMOUNT,AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_TYPE,
                     AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_DATE,AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_AMOUNT,AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_AMOUNT.subtract(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.AMOUNT_REFUNDED.add(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.AMOUNT_APPLIED)));
```

Here you can see a complex select with some calculation

```
ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_AMOUNT.subtract(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.AMOUNT_REFUNDED.add(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.AMOUNT_APPLIED))
```

How to create Alias for this? And then get back data from it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got the solution we can use this

```
AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.PAYMENT_AMOUNT.subtract(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.AMOUNT_REFUNDED.add(AccountPayment.ACCOUNT_PAYMENT.AMOUNT_APPLIED)).as("OverPayment")
```

We have to add `as("Alias Name")` and getting value back we have to use

```
     Result<Record> resultPayment = selectQueryPayment.fetch();
           for(Record record : resultPayment){
           feeAmount =  resultPayment.getValues("OverPayment");
```

}